# Can a first stage be a booster?

Tags: rockets, booster

Wikipedia defines booster as"A booster rocket (or engine) is either the first stage of a multistage launch vehicle, or else a shorter-burning rocket used in parallel with longer-burning sustainer rockets to augment the space vehicle's takeoff thrust and payload capability."

Is this a case of Pedantics of the definition or are boosters always parallely staged?

Comment: ...is **either** the first stage of a multistage launch vehicle, or else a ....

Answer (score 6):

The definition doesn't require staging in parallel. The booster is either the first of multiple stages, or one that drops off a sustainer stage that lit at sea level and keeps climbing post booster-shutdown. It's a rather open and flexible definition, rather than pedantic.